# MySql: Order results by value where value = value in other table

Tags: mysql, sorting

I hope my title makes sense but basically what I need to do is select some rows from a mysql table but I want one particular row to always be listed first.  Normally I would use "order by field" for this but this particular row has to match a value in another table.

```
SCHEDULES TABLE
----------
ID
NAME
COMPANYID
DESCRIPTION


COMPANIES TABLE
----------
ID
NAME
ACTIVESCHEDULEID
```

So I want to select all the schedules from schedules table where companyid = 1, but the schedule that is the active schedule for this company needs to be listed first, and that bit of information is stored in the companies table.

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
select s.id
from schedules s, companies c
where s.companyid = c.id 
and s.companyid = 1 
order by field(s.id,s.id = c.activescheduleid)
```

But that's not working for me.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple conditions in the `order by` clause.  The first can be for a match to the active scheduleid:

```
select s.id
from schedules s join
     companies c
     on s.companyid = c.id 
where s.companyid = 1 
order by (s.id = c.activescheduleid) desc, s.id
```

The `desc` is because a "true" value in MySQL is treated as a `1` and "false" is treated as `0`.  So, this returns `1` for the active schedule id.  For that to appear first, use `desc`.

Comment: Thank you.  So simple, yet it stumped me.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.id
from schedules s, companies c
where s.companyid = c.id 
and s.companyid = 1 
order by
  s.id,
  s.id = c.activescheduleid
```

You might want to use `ASC` or `DESC` for the second order condition, depending on identity sorted first or last.